# Bring an element to the front on button click using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following `css`, `html` and `js` code:

```
<div class="loader_parent" id="loader_parent">
  <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
</div>
<table>
  <thead><tr><td></td></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>

.loader_parent {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1111111;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid gray;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  filter: blur(0px);
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.loader_parent.blurred {
  display: flex;
}

.blurred ~ * {
  filter: blur(0.5px);
}


showLoader = (flag) => {
  let loader = document.querySelector('#loader_parent');
  if (flag) {
    spinner.classList.add('blurred');
  } else {
    spinner.classList.remove('blurred');
  }
};
```

So whenever the `flag` is set to true, the `loader` is shown and vice versa. At present, the loader is shown above the table element. What I want is to show the loader element in front of table. So that table remains in the same position and not go down whenever loader is shown. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: `front` ? you mean on your `table` ?

Comment: Use [z-index](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) for positioning things

Comment: @Pedram Yes. Right now `loader_parent` is being displayed on top of the table. This makes the table go down whenever loader_parent is displayed. I only want to display loader_parent but the table should be where it is. So loader_parent should come in front of table.

Comment: @Roy I have used `z-index`. It makes the loader in front but also the loader is on top of the table. I only want the loader to be in front of the table and not on top of it.

Comment: I want to display it like how `alert` is displayed. In front of other elements. But other elements should not move in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `position: absolute` on your loader and also wrap all contents to a container with relative position, and for make it center:

```
.loader_parent {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; // center from x
  right: 0; // center from x
  margin: auto; // center from x
  top: 50%; // center from y
  transform: translateY(-50%); // center from y
}
```

```js
showLoader = (flag) => {
  let loader = document.querySelector('#loader_parent');
  let spinner = document.querySelector('.loader_parent');
  if (flag) {
    spinner.classList.add('blurred');
  } else {
    spinner.classList.remove('blurred');
  }
};

$('#goload').click(function() {
  showLoader(true)
});
```

```css
table.table tr td {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

table.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.loader_parent {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid gray;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  filter: blur(0px);
  margin: auto;
}


/* Safari */

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loader_parent.blurred {
  display: block;
}

.blurred~* {
  filter: blur(0.5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="loader_parent" id="loader_parent">
    <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
  </div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="goload">Click</button>
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use `flex` to position `loader_parent`?

Comment: @Lax_Sam no, if you want to bring an element on other element the only ways is `absolute` position not `flex` or etc

Comment: Oh ok. Got it! `flex` only aligns elements side by side?

Comment: @Lax_Sam yes exactly